# How do i resolved 'HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error' in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, iis-express, iis-10

I am trying to access a gateway link of my software which is `localhost:7500`. But I am trying to access this link it is showing me this error.

[image]

Also I am not able to open anything in IIS. Whenever i try to open any thing it is showing me this error.

[image]

For IIS features i have installed below features:

a)  ASP.NET 4.6  b) ISAPI Extensions  c)    ISAPI Filters  d)   .NET Extensibility 4.6  e)  IIS Management Console f)   IIS Management Scripts and tools g) Request Filtering (from Security) h) Windows Authentication(from Security)
From features-  i)   Net Framework 4.6

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html#background

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try the following methods to solve the problem.

1. Install the URL rewrite module. you can install it by below link:
   https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
2. Go to the Application pool, Open the Advanced Settings of Application Pool, Change the .Net CLR version from 'V4.0' to 'No Managed Code'.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today and below is how I fixed this problem;

- Check that you have installed the [IIS URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module. If not, install it.
  [image]
- Check that your local app's App pool is set correctly.
  [image]
- Check that the anonymous user on the website is set to app pool identity.
  [image]
- You can additionally grant Everyone full control of the whole website folder.